# bcrypt.compare always returns false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

I am trying to get a login function going but when I try to compare password with hashed password it always returns false

This is my registerUser function that holds the hashing

```
const registerUser = async (request, response) => {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(request.body.password, 12)
    const user = new UserModel({
        username: request.body.username,
        password: hashedPassword
    });

    try {
        const databaseResponse = await user.save();
        response.status(201).send(databaseResponse);
    } catch (error) {
        response.status(500).send({message: error.message});
    }
};
```

This is the login function that holds the compare

```
const login = async (request, response) => {
    try{
        const user = await UserModel.findOne({username: request.body.username})
        if(!user) return response.status(403).send('no user with name ' + request.body.username + ' found');
        const isPassValidated = await bcrypt.compare(request.body.password, user.password)
        if(!isPassValidated) return response.status(403).send('wrong password');
        response.status(200).send('yay');
    } catch(error){
        response.status(500).send({message: error.message});
    }
}
```

When I console.log request.body.password and user.password the hashed string is equal to the unhashed string so it should return true

[image: screenshot]

The hashed string is the same string that is saved in the database

Comment: how about trimming the password from the request, or checking the char encoding?

Comment: I would also suggest you create a unit test with the encryption/decryption code only, so you can discard everything else, at least at first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the issue, thank you for your help. in userSchema, password was lowercase:true which caused the issue...

Answer (score 0):

The code looks alright. Do you have multiple users with the same username in your database? The generated hash should be: `$2b$12$jgrLYOqnHnJGszlpgo26QuaT29tdxBFguyIttSNOIy/8go1viRrYC`

[image: Recreated]